# best way to load css on server side rendering using Nodejs with React-Redux (Universal App)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, isomorphic-style-loader

what is the best way to load css on server side rendering with React-Redux (Universal App)

Note: server side performance is priority.

For Ex: Isomorphic-style-loader or react-style or Any other.

Comment: Show us what you've tried.

Comment: You can also have a look at [webpack-plugin-critical](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-plugin-critical), you can search for "inline critical path css" for additional resources.

Comment: I have implemented isomorphic-style-loader. is there any production issues with this? (present am in development state).

Comment: How did you implement isomorphic-style-loader, I have issues with it. Would you mind sharing some tips?

Comment: in server side file:  const context = { insertCss: (...styles) => {
    //console.log('executing');
    return styles.forEach(function(style) {css.add(style._getCss())})
   } 
 };  <ContextProvider context={context}><App/></ContextProvider> contextprovider.js                  class ContextProvider extends React.Component {  
  getChildContext() {
    return { ...this.props.context }} render () {const { children, ...props } = this.props
    return React.cloneElement(children, props);
  }}ContextProvider.childContextTypes = {
    insertCss: PropTypes.func,}